# Licensing error with System.Windows.Forms, Version=6.0.2.0?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am getting some really weird errors relocating a project over to a new pc. I am using VS 2022 with NET Core 6. The error on the newer pc is as follows:

LC : error LC0000: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)'

I thought maybe one of my 3rd party controls could be causing this so I removed ALL of them and I still got the same error.

So I decided on the newer pc to start a new NET Core 6 project and it compiles and runs just fine with the same System.Windows.Forms reference. I even went into my solution explorer and drilled down into my references to compare the broken project with the fresh brand new one. Both use the same .dll with the versions matching exactly.

I've nuked my bin folder and have tried several other things to no avail. I noticed it says the error is "LC" which I googled and found that has to do with licensing? I don't really have any knowledge on that subject. Has anybody seen this before or knows what could be the underlying issue?

Below is a picture of my dotnet --info. The blue screen is the working pc and the black is the non-working..

Thanks

[image]

Here is the .vbproj contents of my main project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject>Sub Main</StartupObject>
    <MyType>WindowsForms</MyType>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.2202.400</AssemblyVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DocumentationFile>MyPortal.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DocumentationFile>MyPortal.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>MyPortal.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Authors></Authors>
    <PackageIcon>MyPortal.png</PackageIcon>
    <PackageIconUrl />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Classes\cls_DoubleBufferedDGV.vb" />
    <Compile Update="Custom Controls\QuestionCheckbox.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>QuestionCheckbox.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Custom Controls\QuestionCheckbox.vb">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Custom Controls\QuestionTextbox.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>QuestionTextbox.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Custom Controls\QuestionTextbox.vb">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Custom Controls\QuestionYesNo.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>QuestionYesNo.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Custom Controls\QuestionYesNo.vb">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Custom Controls\Callout.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>Callout.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Custom Controls\Callout.vb">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="frm_ExtendAccounts.designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frm_ExtendAccounts.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="frm_PhoneNumbers.designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frm_PhoneNumbers.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Generic Forms\frmAuth.designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frmAuth.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Generic Forms\frmListItemEditor.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frmListItemEditor.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Generic Forms\frmListItemPicker.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frmListItemPicker.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Generic Forms\frmNewQuestion.designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frmNewQuestion.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Generic Forms\frmPleaseWait.designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frmPleaseWait.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="frm_Permissions.designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frm_Permissions.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Generic Forms\frmAutoADSearchbox.designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frmAutoADSearchbox.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Generic Forms\frmLists.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frmLists.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Generic Forms\frmQuestions.designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frmQuestions.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Generic Forms\Inputbox.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>Inputbox.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="My Project\Application.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Application.myapp</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="My Project\Settings.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="frm_Splash_Startup.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frm_Splash_Startup.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="My Project\licenses.licx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="My Project\Application.myapp">
      <Generator>MyApplicationCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Application.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <None Update="My Project\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <None Include="..\.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
    <None Include="Resources\MyPortal.png">
      <Pack>True</Pack>
      <PackagePath>
      </PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json" />
    <Content Include="MyPortal-Icons\MyPortal.ico" />
    <Content Include="MyPortal-Icons\MyPortal.png" />
    <Content Include="MyPortal-Icons\MyPortal_TestBranch.ico" />
    <Content Include="MyPortal-Icons\MyPortal_TestBranch.png" />
    <Content Include="Notes\Notes.txt" />
    <Content Include="SQL Queries\Create-List-Table.sql" />
    <Content Include="SQL Queries\Create-Templates-Table.sql" />
    <Content Include="SQL Queries\Database Query.sql" />
    <Content Include="SQL Queries\Create-GAMDelegates-Table.sql" />
    <Content Include="SQL Queries\Create-MyPortalPermissions-Table.sql" />
    <Content Include="SQL Queries\Create-UserForms-Table.sql" />
    <None Include="Resources\user %281%29.png" />
    <None Include="Resources\refresh %281%29.png" />
    <Content Include="External Refrences\Interop.ActiveDs.dll" />
    <Content Include="Local Settings\Settings.xml" />
    <Content Include="MyPortal.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Include="..\packages\Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers.0.3.310801\analyzers\dotnet\vb\Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers.Common.dll" />
    <Analyzer Include="..\packages\Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers.0.3.310801\analyzers\dotnet\vb\Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers.dll" />
    <Analyzer Include="..\packages\Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers.0.3.310801\analyzers\dotnet\vb\Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.CodeFixes.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="UI.for.WinForms.AllControls.Net60">
      <Version>2022.2.622.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Custom Controls\CommentPanel.Designer.vb" />
    <Compile Remove="Custom Controls\CommentPanel.vb" />
    <Compile Remove="Custom Controls\ListViewCollapsible.vb" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Custom Controls\CommentPanel.resx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <UserProperties ShouldAddDPIScalingManifest="True" />
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="SQL Queries\Create-Templates-Table.sql" />
    <None Remove="User Forms\ldwise2e.exy~" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DevComponents.DotNetBar2">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\DotNetBar for Windows Forms\DevComponents.DotNetBar2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="My Project\Resources.resx">
      <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
      <Generator>PublicVbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is the .vbproj of the test app I created to see if it will work on the new pc:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject>Sub Main</StartupObject>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <MyType>WindowsForms</MyType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="System.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="My Project\Application.Designer.vb">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Application.myapp</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="My Project\Application.myapp">
      <Generator>MyApplicationCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Application.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is the screenshot of my Nuget packages.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is the output of `dotnet --info` the same on old vs new pc?

Comment: No it is not. I will post a screenshot.

Comment: "blue" is the new machine right? there you are missing the .net runtimes for 6.0.2 (the version corresponding to your winform dll).  Try to install either the sdk 6.0.2 or the .net desktop runtime 6.0.2 this might probably solve your problem. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0. Or upgrade to 6.0.6

Comment: Blue is the old machine. That machine works

Comment: hmm that is funny.. can you post also the csproj of the winform project vs the project that works?

Comment: It's vbproj and sure.

Comment: I am installing vs on another virtual machine on the network I am going to see if that gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you take out  `<ItemGroup><FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" /></ItemGroup>`  that doesn't belong there.

 `UI.for.WinForms.AllControls.Net60` can you check what it depends on ? That could be a reason why it's behaving that way.

Comment: I remored the AspNetCore reference. I The AllControls.Net60 is Telerik controls for windows which is used in my project. I still receive the same error I am about to test on the other machine in a few min I will update on my findings.

Comment: Can you please check what the telerik controls are referencing (in nuget)? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I was able to get another virtual machine setup and it also failed with the same error. I will post the screenshot of my nuget installs...ty so much for attempting to help me <3

Comment: You'll need help from the vendor, start [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/winforms).

Comment: I don't think this is related to Telerik? Seems it has something to do with the licensing compiler "LC" which is an executable that controls licensing for 3rd party addons? I may be incorrect but it looks like a MS product. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/lc-exe-license-compiler

Comment: So I did some googling and decided to google the PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 which is in the error message. I found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d2fdbbd-d0e5-4c4c-aa7b-6ddca20529b8/publickeytokenb77a5c561934e089-failed?forum=vblanguage which looks like it could be a security issue. Still researching.

Comment: Maybe the DevComponents.DotNetBar2? Does it need a license that has been installed on the old machine but not on the new?

Comment: I spent some time changing my code and  have completely removed that package (DotNetBar2). The error still occurs. I have opened a ticket with Telerik to see what they have to say. I think this has something to do with the lc.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by going into my license.licx file and deleting all of the contents from the file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="YourDllFile" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-YourDllFileVersion" newVersion="YourDllFileVersion" />
```

- set DeleteExistingFiles = true
  update all nugget packages and rebuild.

Comment: Hello, where do I try this at?